# Client Area Flickers when Drawing a Line

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

The problem I am having is that when I draw my line, the screen flickers every time it redraws. I just can't quite figure out how to not make it flicker. I understand the flicker is coming from me redrawing the client area hundreds of times a second as I move my mouse with my left button down but how would I be able to get around this?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
                          WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
     {
     static HDC      hdc;
     PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
     RECT            rect;
     RECT            size;
     static POINT   point1;
     static POINT   point2;
     static HBRUSH  origBrush;
     static bool    drawingLine = false;

     switch (message)
         {

         case WM_CREATE:
             origBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0 , 0) );

             break;

          case WM_PAINT:
                hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);

                GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect);

                GetWindowRect(hwnd, &size);

                Rectangle(hdc, 10, 10, 80, 80 );

                if(drawingLine == true)
                {
                    MoveToEx(hdc, point1.x, point1.y, NULL);
                    LineTo(hdc, point2.x, point2.y);
                }

                EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
                return 0;

                //Has all the commands that exist in your program.
          case WM_COMMAND:
              switch(LOWORD(wParam))
              {
              case ID_COLOR_RED:
                  break;

              case ID_COLOR_BLUE:
                  break;

              case ID_COLOR_BLACK:
                  break;

              case ID_THICKNESS_1:
                  break;

              case ID_THICKNESS_2:
                  break;

              case ID_THICKNESS_3:
                  break;

              }
              break;

          case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
              drawingLine = true;
              SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
              point1.x = LOWORD(lParam);
              point1.y = HIWORD(lParam);
              MoveToEx(hdc, point1.x, point1.y, NULL);
              break;

          case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
              point2.x = LOWORD(lParam);
              point2.y = HIWORD(lParam);
              InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, 1);
              break;

          case WM_LBUTTONUP:
              point2.x = LOWORD(lParam);
              point2.y = HIWORD(lParam);

              drawingLine = false;
              break;

              //Causes the program to exit.
          case WM_DESTROY:
              PostQuitMessage(0);
              break;
         }
```

Comment: Look up double buffering.

Comment: If you're not handling `WM_ERASEBKGND` then the system will be clearing your entire client area every time you invalidate it.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to do is respond to `WM_ERASEBKGND` and return true to prevent the default re-drawing of the background.

Then you'll need to erase the old line you before drawing the new one. Just for example, you might save bits from under the line, draw it, then restore those (and only those) pixels before drawing the line, so when you need to erase it, you can just restore those pixels to erase it.

The obvious alternative (that's usually simpler though theoretically at least a little slower) is to use double buffering. Do roughly the drawing you are now, but to an off-screen bitmap. Then, when it's all complete just BitBlt from there to the screen.